# JQuery create HTML object

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I look at the JQuery doc @ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2, it says

> ...If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML ...

However, what if I want this behavior to occur all the time? I'm passing in a variable to `$()`, and I always want the variable to be interpreted as a HTML, not selector.

One way to do it is wrap the variable with a `<span>` tag, I don't want to add unnecessary DOM to the tree.

Comment: Can you give an example of a string that jQuery mistakes for a selector? *(For the record, I think this is one of the areas where jQuery's API is just horrible -- the `$` function does, what, four different things, at least two of which aren't even distinguished by the type of the argument, but still...do you have an example?)*

Comment: @T.J.: amen brother. I think `$` actually does 7 distinct things, [6 of them documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), the other [not so much](http://api.jquery.com/link/) (see the syntax for setting property values on an object literal). What a mess.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: Re that last one: OMG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you want to be absolutely certain, without having control of the variable's contents, you'll have to do the wrapper thing or use [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) or [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead, since those APIs aren't ambiguous. If you can, do the latter, because the wrapper thing can bite you. (For instance, if the variable contains a table row that will ultimately be appended to a table, you can't use a `span` or `div` wrapper; but you can't use a `table` wrapper for something that *isn't* a table row.)

For instance, instead of

```
$(varname).appendTo(dest);
```

you can do

```
dest.append(varname); // Or $(dest).append(varname) if `dest` isn't already a jQuery instance
```

...and instead of

```
$(varname).replaceAll(targets);
```

you'd do

```
targets.replaceWith(varname); // Or $(targest).replaceWith(varname)
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable will be interpreted as the value it references. So if your variable contains `"<span>"`, you'll get a `span` element back.

```
var tag = "<span>";

var $span = $( tag ); // returns a new span DOM element wrapped in a jQuery object
```

or if you meant that the variable will only contain the tag name `"span"`, then concatenate the brackets.

```
var tag = "span";

var $span = $( "<" + tag + ">" );
```

---

**EDIT:** jQuery lets you create DOM elements this way. If you wanted to create something else like a text node, you can use a container as you suggested, but you don't need to add it to the DOM.

```
var txt = "this will be a text node";

var textNode = $( "<span>", {text: txt} ).contents();
```

If you append `textNode` to the DOM, you will only be getting the content of the span.

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery 1.8 (currently in beta), they're introducing $.parseHTML, which is suppose to perform this task.

http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/22/jquery-1-8-beta-1-see-whats-coming-and-going/

Answer (score 0):

HTML passed to jQuery will get converted to DOM elements, but only valid HTML.  If you pass a tag properly `<tag>` or hierarchy thereof you'll get converted code.  If you pass random text, <strike>unbalanced tags</strike> or something odd, you'll get a selector of some description.

Comment: Unbalanced tags are alright when creating elements in this manner. jQuery treats `$('<div>')`, `$('<div/>')` and `$('<div></div>')` the same.

Comment: Individually it allows it, for a single element, and obviously it allows the self-closed (and therefore self-balanced) shortcut `<tag />`.  I meant for more complex structures.

Comment: OK, I see what you were saying. Although in the case of unbalanced or mismatched tags, it will still be considered HTML and will use the browser's `innerHTML` to create the elements. The browser will make corrections as it sees fit. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/aJtVg/) of some really bad HTML being passed, and the result the browser provides.

Comment: @patrick Aye, an interesting exercise - note the browser differences. IE: `<DIV><SPAN>I'm a span<P></P></DIV>`; Chrome: `<div><span>I'm a span<p></p></span></div>`; FF: `<div><span>I'm a span</span></div>`.  All different!  My answer is wrong regarding the unbalanced tags, I will strike that. Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with "HTML object" ?

If you mean a string without any HTML-Elements included, you can create a textNode of it and assign this to $() :

```
$(document.createTextNode(variable))
```